# Testing for functions called from a list in python

Tags: python

I want to know, how can I test for a function randomly pulled from a list in a conditional statement? Here is some example code. Just ignore what the code is supposed to be printing.

```
import random, time
def biomeLand():
    print "Biome: Land"

def biomeOcean():
    print "Biome: Ocean"

def biomeDesert():
    print "Biome: Desert"

def biomeForest():
    print "Biome: Forest"

def biomeRiver():
    print "Biome: River"

biomes = [biomeLand, biomeOcean, biomeDesert, biomeForest,
          biomeRiver]

def run():
    while True:
        selected_biome = random.choice(biomes)()
        time.sleep(0.5)
run()
```

Once again how can I make it so the program tests in a conditional statement when a certain function is called from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just match them like any other variable:

```
def foo():
    print "foo"

def bar():
    print "bar"

first = foo

print (first == bar) # prints "False"
print (first == foo) # prints "True"
```

So in your example you can just have something like:

```
if selected_biome == biomeLand:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
def run():
    while True:
        selected_biome = random.choice(biomes)
        selected_biome()
        if selected_biome == biomeLand:
            print "biomeLand Selected"
        time.sleep(0.5)
run()
```